# Conflict between \hline and arydshln in aligned environment?

Tags: align, arydshln

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{arydshln} %code doesn't compile anymore with this package

\begin{document}    
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0){$\begin{aligned}
                  & A \to B\\
                  & A \\\hline  
                  & B
                 \end{aligned}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

to produce this (the actual formula is a bit longer but I don't think that does matter):

[image]

Problem is that in other parts of the document I need to use the `\hdashline` macro from the `arydshln` package and it seems that the package conflicts with the `\hline` macro when placed inside the `aligned` environment.

I tried replacing `\hline` with `\cline` and `\hhline` but both produce something like this:

[image]

with too much whitespace around the horizontal line.

Is there a way to have an horizontal line like`\hline` in an `aligned` environment while the `arydshln` is loaded? It would be ok also to change the environment to something else, assuming it works inside a TikZ node.

Comment: What about `$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}` instead of `aligned`?

Comment: @egreg works! thanks. Is it also possible to move up the horizontal line a bit? As it is it almost touches the "B."

Comment: `\extrarowheight` of the `array` package might help.

Comment: @egreg, sorry, nevermind, it works just fine as it is, the line I was seeing was another one I was drawing with TikZ for test purpose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aligned` environment is not based on `tabular` or `array`, so `\hline` and similar commands are not guaranteed to work; this is definitely true, it seems, for the extended lines provided by `arydshln`.

Use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)
  {$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    A \to B\\
    A \\
    \hdashline
    B
    \end{array}$
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]